# Facebook Login and UIWebview

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, uiwebview

I'm currently developing an app that is essentially a single WebView that allows access to a specific website (terrible idea I know, but the decision comes from higher up); said website offers the option to login through Facebook with the standard Facebook Connect procedure.

The login process works fine in Mobile Safari but unfortunately when a UIWebView attempts to do the same thing after authorizing a blank page is displayed and nothing happens. This is of course because of the page actually being just a JavaScript that communicates with the original page through postMessage (I think!).

I tried searching and while this is a pretty widely recognized problem all the solutions I found are either not applicable or won't work. I found somewhere that it's possible to pass mode=redirect to the oauth URL to prevent the whole process to involve popups which sounds promising but as far as I tell it doesn't work.

Is there a way to make Facebook Connect work **for a website inside a UIWebView**? I'm considering the option of having the Facebook button call a special URL that I would then listen to inside the ap to trigger a native authentication process but unfortunately since my company is not the one developing the website so this kind of solution would be the least preferred.

Comment: Probably this is the best scenario to tell your boss that this is wrong in so many ways.

Comment: Ha ha I know, but unfortunately he was the one who essentially sold the app to the client assuming everything would be hunky-dory so I'm not holding my breath on that one

Comment: I know it has been a while since this was active, but I was wondering whether you figured out a solution? I am facing the same issue at the moment.

Comment: IIRC we worked around it by using a User Agent that contained the standard iOS User Agent rather than a completely different one and the process seemed to work fine that way. I'm sorry I can't be of any help but it's been a while since I worked on this project and I can't recall what we eventually did in order to make it work